# Python subprocess locale settings 

Tags: python, opennlp

When executing `opennlp POSTagger` with `subprocess.call` in python, the result goes wrong. But when I put the same command into my terminal, the result is correct.

After some testing , I think this is because `opennlp` failed to load the model file correctly, so what's the problem? The model is trained in Chinese and I use python 2.7.

OpenNLP runs without any warnings or errors, but it tags the input sentence totally wrong. It gives the correct tags in the terminal. I guess it's an encoding problem but I'm not sure.

Here is the code. It's nothing special and contains only ascii chars.
Print this command and copy it to terminal, the result is correct.

Now I know it's the locale/encoding problem (debug the script by strace). But it's of no use to set the python locale to `en_US.utf-8` or `zh_CN.utf-8`. My shell locale setting is `zh_CN.utf-8`.

```python
opennlp_path = './opennlp/bin/opennlp'
pos_model = 'train.pos.model'
pos_predict_cmd = [opennlp_path, 'POSTagger', pos_model]
subproc = call(pos_predict_cmd)
```

Comment: good chance something is different between your shell environment and your subprocess environment, but it's easier to diagnose if you post the errors

Comment: Why do you execute it through a shell? Usually that's not a good idea.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks for your suggestion. But the problem remains if executing the command without a shell. :(

Comment: @Shep Well, the error is that opennlp tags the input sentences totally incorrect.

Comment: "the result goes wrong"--does this mean it runs successfully, but produces incorrect results?  Or does it crash?  Also, please include the values of `opennlp_path` and `pos_model`.

Comment: @reasonsolo, not sure if I follow, what error does it print? Also, if you can clarify this question, it's best to edit the question rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module, read it once or twice, then try using `call(pos_predict_cmd, shell=True)` and see if that works.

Comment: It might be that subprocess runs your command with a different shell environment than what it used when you run the command directly from the terminal. Try adding `print os.environ` to your script and compare that to the `env` output from the terminal.